# I am struggling with the abstraction of a parsing function for a text line with comma-separated fields with a known number and their type

Tags: c++

I am trying to parse a line with a fixed amount of fields and known types.

```
using Text = FieldType<std::string>;
using Int = FieldType<int>;

using Name = Text;
using TextSpecificField = Text;
using IntSpecificField = Int;

struct LineData
{
    Name name;
    TextSpecificField textField;
    IntSpecificField intField;
    // LineData contains 12 fields in total, types are known
};

struct InvalidLine { std::string line, err; };

using Line = std::variant<LineData, InvalidLine>;
```

This allows me to write a parsing function for each specific field type:

```
template<Field T>
constexpr auto parse(std::string_view field) -> detail::ReturnOptErr<T>
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Text, T>)
    {
        return {decltype(T::value){field}};
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Int, T>)
    {
        auto [value, err] = toNum<decltype(T::value)>(field); // Why typename T::value doesn't work?
        return {T{value}, std::move(err)};
    }
    else
    {
        []<bool flag = false> { static_assert(flag, "no match"); }();
    }
}
```

This is where my problem starts with the following parse function. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around trying to simplify this piece of code. As you can see, there is a repeating pattern that I would like to abstract:

```
auto parse(std::string_view line) -> Line
{
    // Parsing a string and returning string is done intentionally to show repeating pattern
    auto [nameStr, rest] = split(line, ',');
    auto name = parse<Name>(nameStr);
    if (name.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(name.errorText.value())};
    }

    auto [textStr, rest2] = split(rest, ',');
    auto textField = parse<TextSpecificField>(textStr);
    if (textField.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(textField.errorText.value())};
    }

    auto [intStr, rest3] = split(rest2, ',');
    auto intField = parse<IntSpecificField>(intStr);
    if (intField.errorText)
    {
        return InvalidLine{std::string{line}, std::move(intField.errorText.value())};
    }

    return LineData{std::move(name.value), std::move(textField.value), intField.value};
}
```

Is there an elegant way to approach this? I thought about using exceptions, but I don't like that solution. I also tried to approach this problem using [template recursion](https://godbolt.org/z/aaTWc8sMd), but I could not come up with an idea of returning `Line` from such a parser.

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/1b4rxr5Kh)

BR

Comment: Elegant approach is to use Flex and Bison for parsing

Comment: Could you factor the repeated code out into a template helper function? That seems like it would address the repeated code issue.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean @templatetypedef. I think, if I put code into the helper function I still have to check the return type if the parsing of a field was successful.
I tried the templated approach, and I failed to come up with a working solution.

Comment: @DmitryMesserman That's overkill for parsing a line. There is no grammar here.

Comment: @Norbert Could you have the helper throw an exception if the input is bad that the main function translates into an error code? Or perhaps have a helper that takes in the previous error, does nothing if an error happened, and otherwise parses more and updates the error?

Comment: @MartinYork It depends. I never use C++ parsers. So far so good.

Comment: @DmitryMesserman Thank you for the suggestion, but I decided to make a handwritten C++ parser. It is rather a simple pet project that I would like to work on.